# Figuring out what Javascript object is this?

Tags: javascript

I have some script that has the following code:

```
var result = {
    id:   'test',
    name: 'test',
    home: 'test',
ex_info: [{date: new Date('12-31-2010'), quantity: 976}],
    status: ''
}
```

I am trying to insert information in the ex_info property. But I can't add anything. I try to hard to code the following:

```
var result = {
    id:   'test',
    name: 'test',
    home: 'test',
ex_info: [{date: new Date('03-31-2010'), quantity: 976}, {date: new Date('02-31-2010'), quantity: 543}],
    status: ''
}
```

But it results in an error:

*Update:*

Error: Expected [ { date : Date(Fri Mar 31 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)), quantity : 976 }, { date : Date(Thu Mar 03 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)), quantity : 543 } ] to equal [ { date : Date(Fri Mar 31 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), quantity : 976 } ]

Comment: What does variable `test` hold?

Comment: What is the error?  What is "jasmine.js"?  Why do you want to "insert information" in that property; what are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: That's the correct way - maybe the code does not support more than one item in the ex_info array. Post full error message and we'll know better.

Comment: +1 for you Shadow Wizard. I updated the post

Comment: jasmine.js is a DOM-less simple JavaScript testing framework. Anyway, the error does not show there anymore.

Comment: That sounds like an error message of a library you use. What function do you feed/does read `result`?

Comment: @Thorpe so is it working now? If not please elaborate what's the current problem..

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @ Marcel Korpel. That's what I'm thinking.

Comment: OK, waiting for more details.. we can't possibly help if you now don't have error message and you don't explain it any further. :/

Comment: Hi, Shadow Wizard. I believe Marcel's right about the script. the function that uses result is the problem. It didn't expect me to enter more than 1 ex_info hashes.

Comment: If anyone could post your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct way to append item  to ex_info array.

Probably the code using "result" does not support more than one item in that array.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable test is undefined.  I imagine you meant to encompass that in a string:

```
var result = {
    id:   'test',
    name: 'test',
    home: 'test',
ex_info: [{date: new Date('03-31-2010'), quantity: 976}, {date: new Date('02-31-2010'), quantity: 543}],
    status: ''
}
```

Comment: That hypothesis is not supported by the text of the error message as posted.

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways of instantiating a date:

- new Date() = current date and time
- new Date(ms) = milliseconds since
  1970/01/01
- new Date(dateString)
- new Date(year, month, day, hours,
  minutes, seconds, milliseconds)